# Rewrite Oracle SQL to MYsql

Tags: mysql, oracle

this is my Oracle code

```
SELECT CZAS_W CZAS , SYSTEM_W SYSTEM,  'ALL', sum(NVL(STAN, 0)) STAN FROM (
  select '2018-02-06 '||A.CZAS CZAS_W, A.SYSTEM SYSTEM_W, A.PRACOWNIK PRACOWNIK_W, A.STATUS, L.PRACOWNIK, L.CZAS, L.SYSTEM, L.STAN
  from GC_ALWAYS A , O2MT_GC2_LICENCJI_LOG L
  WHERE A.SYSTEM = L.SYSTEM (+)
    AND A.PRACOWNIK = L.PRACOWNIK (+)
    AND TO_DATE('2018-02-06 '||A.CZAS, 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI') = L.CZAS  (+)
    AND A.SYSTEM = 'HURT06OTO' )
   group by CZAS_W  , SYSTEM_W
```

In Oracle it runs in 226 ms. (No index in use)

I have rewritten it to MySQL:

```
SELECT s1.CZAS_W CZAS , s1.SYSTEM_W SYSTEM,  'ALL', sum(ifnull(s1.STAN, 0)) STAN FROM (
select STR_TO_DATE(concat("2018-02-06 ",A.CZAS), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') CZAS_W, A.SYSTEM SYSTEM_W, A.PRACOWNIK PRACOWNIK_W, A.STATUS, L.PRACOWNIK, L.CZAS, L.SYSTEM, L.STAN
    from GC_ALWAYS A
     LEFT OUTER JOIN O2MT_GC2_LICENCJI_LOG L ON A.SYSTEM = L.SYSTEM
        and A.PRACOWNIK = L.PRACOWNIK  
        and STR_TO_DATE(concat("2018-02-06 ",A.CZAS), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = L.CZAS    
  WHERE A.SYSTEM = 'HURT06OTO'    
    ) s1   group by s1.CZAS_W  , s1.SYSTEM_W
```

But the run time is more than 1000 seconds!

The DB's are on different server. But I think that something is wrong in my MySQL version of code.

In oracle I use (+) syntax for outer join. Did I messed up something whit the joins in mysql?

And yes, two tables joined by 3 columns all by left outer join.

Comment: If you don't use indexes then you can't expect decent performance. Re performance generally google the official MySQL documentation re optimization & re indexes. Also google sargability. RDMBS implementation is all about optimization. PS Oracle itself deprecates its `(+)` notation. Also please see [mcve].

Comment: What does the explain plan show you? Start there to help debug performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are crucial, but putting that to one side, the part to focus on is this:

`AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT("2018-02-06 ",a.czas), '%y-%m-%d %h:%i') = l.czas`

If you can rewrite that without the functions, performance will be greatly enhance.